# Фокус на элементе в scrolllist

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня имеется scrolllist элементами которого являются несколько панелей, с расположенными на них элементами.

На одной из этих панелей находится элемент, который имеет значение, допустим, "active".

Мне необходимо чтобы при сразу после загрузки сцены произошел автоматический скролл до данного элемента на одной из панелей.

[image: схема].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `ScrollRect` есть свойство [verticalNormalizedPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-verticalNormalizedPosition.html), которое принимает значение от 0 до 1. Т.е. от одного крайнего положения до другого. Быстрый вариант выглядит так:

- Нужно запомнить значение этого `verticalNormalizedPosition`, когда докрутили до этого элемента и он стал активным. Если его по дефолту делаем активным, тогда придется рассчитать расстояние прокрутки, например  единицу поделить на количество элементов.
- Устанавливаем некий флаг, для отслеживания прокрутки по вертикали `LerpV`. и на основе него в `Update` делаем прокрутку на основе [Mathf.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) и [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html). Как пример:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class ScrollRectSnap : MonoBehaviour {

        ScrollRect scroll;

        bool LerpV;
        float targetV;

        void Start ()
        {
            scroll = gameObject.GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
            scroll.inertia = false;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if(LerpV)
            {
                scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Lerp( scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition, targetV, 10*scroll.elasticity*Time.deltaTime);

                if(Mathf.Approximately(scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition, targetV)) 
                    LerpV = false;            
            }
        }
    }
```

где `targetV` - туда, куда надо крутить.